# Export blocks added as default content

Tags: 8, blocks, layout-builder

I am using Layout Builder to add blocks into my nodes. I am adding several instances of different custom block types to specific content individually.

I wander if it is it possible to export those blocks added to node through layout builder as a default content using: [Default content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) module?

I have tried standard `drush dce` and while it exports the node, I could not find block data into exported JSON.

I tried `drush dcer` to export references as well but no luck with it as well.

I am thinking finding specific block IDs and export those entities manually one by one but before I do that I want to find out if there is a way to do it in more elegant fashion.

Also if this something new, it would be good feature to contribute to Default content module, so if we find out that's the case I would happily try to contribute.

Comment: Looks like it is a core issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2942975

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible. Core patch is required to fix this issue. It will fix node JSON structure and attach block_content to json files.
See my comment #63 for details:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2942975#comment-13315805